# Decision Trees: elaboration

Tags: machine-learning, computer-science

I am having problems understanding the concept of elaboration when it comes to decision trees.

If decision tree ***D2*** is an elaboration of tree ***Dl*** does this automatically imply that all classifications for D2 and D1 will be the same? That is, in order to elaborate a tree, will I need to ensure that D1 obeys a more-general-than relationship?

Comment: http://ssdi.di.fct.unl.pt/scl/docs/exercises/Exam2008v1_solution.pdf  Question 1.3 If the answer is not ok for you, maybe you can provide some more info e.g. what precisely you'd like to solve, i didn't find any useful info on term "elaboration" - where did you find it,...

Comment: That answer makes sense, providing that elaboration doesn't actually imply a more-general-than relationship.

Basically if it does, then this would mean that D1 is simply a pruned version of D2.

The elaboration term was just from the machine learning book that I'm reading (by Mitchell). So, I guess my question is whether elaboration simply means that it's the original tree + subtree (in which case your answer is fine) or whether it means that  it's the original tree + subtree but that still produce the same classifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common interpretation of "general" in ML, is how well the trained model performs on the test data.

Assumption: **D2 is a pruned tree of over fit tree D1**

Basis: based on your statement "D2 is an elaboration of tree Dl"

Reformatted Question : 
1. Whether the output of pruned tree ( D2 ) and output of overfit tree ( D1 ) will be the same ?

Ans : Maybe depends on use case to use case. Also the predictive power, for some cases pruned tree may have a better predictive power and in others overfit tree may yield better results.

2. For the second part of your question, is open for others to answer :) .